# How to set different ways to delete in oracle, with and without activating a trigger

Tags: oracle, function, oracle11g, triggers, procedure

I'm using oracle 11g the schema follows as:

```
TRANSFER(id_transfer, origin_account, destine_account, amount, date, id_replica)

DELETES(id, table, id_replica, date)
```

Other tables, each have an id_replica as identifier.

I also have a trigger per table, when delete it copies the id_replica deleted in the table DELETES. So if I delete a transfer it first save into DELETES ( id, transfer, id_replica, sysdate), this is for having a record on what I deleted.

**The problem is that now I want to make a delete without activating this trigger, I need to have 2 ways of deleting a row, activating the trigger and save what I delete into the table DELETES, and deleting the row without activating this trigger.**

Some solutions that came to my mind:

1. making 2 different procedures/functions to delete a row en each table, (or just one with the trigger the other one can be done as normal).
2. enabling or disabling the trigger before each delete, this is kind of complicated because its done a lot of times

How do I make a procedure/function to delete a row? Is there other way to do this?

Comment: :If you dont want to log the deleted record in the table `deletes`,then the only way to deactivate the trigger and then perform the delete action ,if you dnt wanna do this operation again and again ,then either you create a procedure say deactivateAndperformDelete,which takes the primary key of the table ,and the very first statement is to deactivate the trigger and perform delete and again activate the trigger after deleting ,this way you can achieve manual activating and deactivating of trigger.

Comment: how do i make this procedure? i have never done one

Comment: :Time now to start reading and implementing [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6009.htm)

Comment: thanks i solved it making a procedure that deletes and insert into DELETES table